# C# Dictionary issue for reference type as Key

Tags: c#

I have class that implements interface as below

```
class Person : IHuman
{
}
```

I have created dictionary as below

```
Dictionary <IHuman, collection<int>> dic = new Dictionary <IHuman, collection<int>>();
```

Now I add one key value pair as belwow

```
dic.Add (person, myCollection);
```

Again when I use containsKey for "same person object and with same HashCode" as below

```
if (dic.ContainsKey(person))
{
    dic[person] = mynewcollection;
}
else
{
    dic.Add (person, mynewcollection);
}
```

Here ContainsKey() returns false and creates one more key value pair with same person object.

I wondered how it possible...
Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is possible, but you should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of your `Person` class. Otherwise keys (i.e. persons) will be compared by reference. And every new instance will be considered different, even if all fields have same values.

Comment: Best answer ! ..

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're overriding `GetHashCode()` or `Equals` incorrectly, basically. We can't really tell without more information - presumably your `Person` class *actually* has some code in it.

However, fundamentally this code is daft:

```
if (dic.ContainsKey(person))
{
    dic[person] = mynewcollection;
}
else
{
    dic.Add (person, mynewcollection);
}
```

In both cases, the dictionary ends up with an entry with a key of `person` and a value of `mynewcollection`... which is *exactly* the same as you get if you just write:

```
dic[person] = mynewcollection;
```

That will add a new entry or overwrite an existing entry as required.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override equals on your person object. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx for more info

Comment: when using in a dictionary key, it is also explicitly required to override `GetHashCode`. Frankly, they always go together - I think MSDN could phrase that more strongly.